# Они стали было искать, что же осталось

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Два вопроса к предложению:

> *После семи лет супружеской жизни они стали было искать, что же
>   осталось от их любви.*

а) Что такое *было* и почему оно имеет нейтральное окончание, если речь идет о двух персонах. Три слова *стали было искать* — это один предикат?

b) Какую функцию имеет слово *же* в этом предложении?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

БЫ́ЛО (без удар.), частица. употр. при прош. вр. глаголов для обозначения, что действие началось, было предположено, начато, но не совершилось. «На ель ворона взгромоздясь, позавтракать было совсем уж собралась, да призадумалась.» Крылов. (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/752814)

Answer (score 2):

a) "Было" здесь частица, которая употребляется при прошедшем времени глагола для обозначения того, что действие началось или предполагалось, но не было закончено в силу каких-то причин. Окончания у нее нет. Я думаю, вы имеете в виду predicate, т. е. по-русски — сказуемое: тогда "стали было искать" является одним целым предикатом (сказуемым).

b) "Же" здесь усилительная частица (ср.: *После семи лет супружеской жизни они стали было искать, что осталось от их любви*.)

Comment: Aer: спасибо за ответ! можно сказать частица ЖЕ дает выска́зыванию выразительность и эмоциональность?

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы знать, кем и когда написана эта фраза.
Выглядит архаично - и это может быть важно для понимания грамматики.

> а) Что такое *было* и почему оно имеет нейтральное окончание, если речь
>   идет о двух персонах.

"Было" сейчас трактуется как частица (см. М_Г), но, возможно, вам будет понятнее, если вспомнить, что "было" в подобных сочетаниях (фазовый глагол + было + инфинитив) это рефлекс утерянного в русском языке давнопрошедшего времени. Это временная форма использовалась, помимо прочего, для передачи действия, результат которого к моменту относительного настоящего перестал действовать. Если не ошибаюсь, это время сохранилось во многих романских, можете сравнить.

Одной из причин потери актуальности результата такого действия как раз и было то, что действие не доведено до конца (или не начато вовсе). Именно в этом значении этот рефлекс давнопрошедшего времени и сохранился в современном русском. Могу лишь добавить, что всего лишь триста лет назад Ломоносов в своей "Грамматике" выделял это время как вполне ещё живое. Сохранилось оно и в украинском, хотя и там большей частью - в поэтических текстах.

> почему оно имеет нейтральное окончание, если речь идет о двух
>   персонах.

Грамматика такова. Оно всегда "среднего рода", количество и даже качество "персон" тут ни при чем.

> Три слова *стали было искать* — это один предикат?

Это единая конструкция, хотя не думаю, что будет правильно называть всю конструкцию "предикатом", слово "предикат" и без того очень много всякого смысла в себе несет.

Это обычное сочетание "фазовый глагол + инфинитив", разбавленное семантическим модификатором. Смысл здесь почти тот же, что и без "было" (стали искать), но "было" в современном языке передает, как уже сказали, логическую незавершенность действия, а раньше могло использоваться и более широко.